# (Django REST) API design: 1 path with multiple query parameters, or multiple paths?

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

Suppose we have the `books` endpoint, at which we can return serialized Book objects. **Most** of the time, these are books already published (so the `future` is omitted), and **most** of the time we will be displaying a Book list **belonging to** some user. (so the user parameter is mostly present and we mostly filter to books that belong to some user)

Example query:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/books?future=true
http://localhost:8000/api/books?user=somebody
http://localhost:8000/api/books?future=true&user=somebody
```

I'm wondering if the above structure looks OK. Other ideas, some seem worse than others, have come to mind. For example, a different optional endpoint/path (instead of the former):

```
// this makes the least sense to me
http://localhost:8000/api/books/somebody?future=true
```

I have also contemplated whether getting those books from the `users` endpoint would make sense:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/users/somebody/books
http://localhost:8000/api/users/somebody/books?future=true
```

And then I can also call:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/users/somebody/settings
```

Do you agree the second option doesn't make sense?

Can the first and 3rd example live beside each other?

I guess what I'm really asking: should it be possible to reach the same exact resources by two different means in REST design? How do you prefer one over the other? When do you enforce only one? when do you allow both (if at all)?

In this case the API endpoints will be consumed by a future iOS app developed by myself, but I don't think that should be relevant to the question.

Comment: It's all a matter of personal preference here, AFAIK there is no standard. I would personally prefer the third version over the second version if books are always accessed for a given user. But then the caveat is that you have to move the books API resources to the users API resources which is sort of a bad design generally. You can also access them through multiple resources - one user-specific while the other is generic. It's all up to you

Comment: @Ken4scholars - so in your opinion implementation #1 and #3 can both exist and it's not considered bad practice? (more than one way to reach the same resources)

Comment: Yes, I don't consider it a bad design because they are accessed for different purposes - one is for books in general, the other is for books related to a user(maybe bookmarked books). What I do consider bad in such a design is that you will be mixing it up the implementations of the Books API in the Users API. To avoid these issues, you could just use a single books API with user filter. Adding the user to the url path only makes sense if that is the only(or main) use case. If you will be needing a generic Books endpoint anyway then it's not very useful